# Call to undefined function get_blog_option()

Tags: plugin-development, functions

In the `functions.php` of my plugin I've added the following code:

```
function relativePathForUploads( $fileinfo )
{
    global $blog_id;
    $path = get_blog_option($blog_id,'siteurl');

    $fileinfo['url'] = str_replace($path,'',$fileinfo['url']);

    return $fileinfo;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'relativePathForUploads');
```

But in the error log I get the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_blog_option()
```

Do I need to include something before I'm able to call `get_blog_option`? If so, what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that function is only available in multisite mode. Try:

```
if(is_multisite()){
  $path = get_blog_option($blog_id,'siteurl');
}else{
  $path = get_option('siteurl');`
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense, why else would you need a blog Id. Must have missed it in the reference manual.